# How do I know that Google Analytics 4 installed with Google Tag Manager is working?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I believe I have followed the instructions for adding Google Tag Manager to the letter -- including adding the scripts to all pages of my website. I then added the tag for Google Analytics 4. I have tested this tag many times via the Preview and Debug mode in Google Analytics. In debug mode, I could see when pages were loading, in terms of the basic functions. I have also gone live and have supposedly had this functioning for a few weeks now. If I monitor the Real-Time Report in Google Analytics , then call up my website, I can see my activities showing up including additional tags for monitoring YouTube videos and their progress. When monitoring the Network activity in the browser debug tools, I see data is being sent and replies (presumably from Google) acknowledging them with a 204 thumbs up.If I go to another computer under another name, I can also get those visits to show in the Real-Time data. However, there has been no data accumulating for website visitors. My website is new and does not get a lot of hits, but it gets many more than GA is reporting. I see something like 23 for the last three weeks. Cloudflare Analytics shows over 1,100 unique visitors in the last month with between 30 and 97 new visitors per day. There must be something simple I have missed but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere through searches or YouTube video aids. How can I install GA4 and know for sure that the data is being accumulated by Analytics at Google? I really want this to work.
[Google Analytics Report -- One Month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJfXj.png)

[Cloudflare One Month Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFdSt.png)
[Cloudflare One Month Unique Visitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuPaU.png)

Comment: Maybe you have a crazy amount of bots that do not execute JS? I think somewhere in Cloudflare there is also a bots report, so you can crosscheck that. I can at least confirm that your code is working (your url is in the screenshots, don't know if that was intentional).

Comment: The URL in the screenshots doesn't matter. Maybe that is more advertising for me. :) I will see about the bots report. Thank you!

Comment: Cloudflare seems to be blocking attacks successfully. Top crawlers in 24 ours Yandex 3; Bing 2

Comment: This question is now moot. Google Analytics is being forsaken in light of the privacy issues now looming. My website will be 'cookie free'.